# Want to get sum of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two database tables.one table call GL and other is GL_TRN table.GL table have all GL details.GL_TRN table have GL transactions.
I want to get sum of each GL.but GL_TRN may not have some GL trasation for some GL.I need a sql query for this one.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Hi... I added picture with sample tables and desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT GL.GL_CODE,
    CASE WHEN SUM(GL_TRN.TRN_AMOUNT) IS NOT NULL 
         THEN SUM(GL_TRN.TRN_AMOUNT) ELSE 0 END  AS 'TOTAL'
 FROM GL
    LEFT JOIN GL_TRN ON GL.GL_CODE = GL_TRN.GL_CODE
 GROUP BY GL.GL_CODE
 GO
```